# where is the Injil?

Tags: previous-scriptures

We have the Torah, We have the Psalms, We have the Quran, where is a copy of the Injil? Is it the same as the Bible Gospels (Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John) and if not where is the "Injil". Who can answer this question?  I have done google search and found where some believe the injil is the Gospel of Jesus... some claim to be lost ... but Muhammend say believe the Torah, Pasls and Gospel.. so is the 4 gospel the injil or not.? simple/

Comment: This question is sorely lacking in details, you show absolutely zero research effort, and your tags are irrelevant. We expect users to put far more effort into their questions than this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"The Injil" is the Bible, which God has revealed to the Prophet, peace be upon him. But Christians have alleged his verses, so he has many versions. John, Luke, and Mighty and Matthew they represent the Bible.

Comment: How is it distorted?  the version are just rewrite from someone view, it does not change what the orginal writers penned.